# Which level is best to get the mountaineer badge

Tags: ios, mirrors-edge

I'm trying to get all the badges on Mirror's Edge for iPhone and the only one I'm missing is the mountaineer one (climb 1,000 meters)

I was thinking that level 5-2 (“Underground”) could be a good fit to get it, but I can't seem to find a couple of pipes close **and** long enough to do the climbing.

Is there a better level to achieve the mountaineer badge? (maybe some of the ones with elevator holes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had a hunch with 3-2 (“Jailbreak”) and got the badge just by climbing from the “Scruffy was here” graffiti to the top of that elevator hole.

But as I've climbed that part a couple of times before and didn't get the badge, it hit me then that the distance for the badge was accumulative. (just like other similar badges like running 10km, ziplining 1km, falling 1km, etc… Doh!).

So just for curiosity's sake, I went back to 5-2 and found the perfect place on the 3rd or 4th water pump:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNlOX.jpg

As you can see on the 2nd image, there's a gap at the top, between the upper platform and the pipe, then at the bottom there's a ramp you can fall safely without getting any damage (3rd image), so you can climb and fall as you please until you get the badge.